# Data Mining of Google Analytics using R

Tags: r, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use this code to access my Google Analytics API, but after running the code I get this error

Error in init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app, scope = self$params$scope.
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401). Failed to get an access token.

```
install.packages("RGoogleAnalytics")
install.packages("googleAuthR")
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
# Authorize the Google Analytics account

client.id <- "########################.com"
client.secret <- "#################_TknUI"
token<-Auth(client.id,client.secret)
```

Comment: You are using googleAuthR but the Google Analytics library it supports is googleAnalyticsR, not RGoogleAnalytics

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
oauth_token <- Auth(
  client.id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
  client.secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
)
oauth_token
# <Token>
#   <oauth_endpoint>
#   authorize: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
# access:    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
# validate:  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo
# revoke:    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke
# <oauth_app> google
# key:    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
# secret: <hidden>
#   <credentials> access_token, expires_in, refresh_token, token_type
# ---


sessionInfo()
# R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
# 
# locale:
#   [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
# [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    
# 
# attached base packages:
#   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
#   [1] RGoogleAnalytics_0.1.1 httr_1.2.1             lubridate_1.6.0       
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#   [1] R6_2.2.0      magrittr_1.5  tools_3.3.2   stringi_1.1.2 stringr_1.1.0
```

Maybe update your packages and/or the oauth endpoints?